# How to play the iPod Library file in the AVPlayer

Tags: iphone, avaudioplayer, mpmusicplayercontroller

How can I get an ipod library music file into AVAudioPlayer?

Comment: I would recommend looking at http://superuser.com/ also you may want to give more detail. What program are you using exactly, and have you done any research so far?

Comment: AVAudioPlayer is a class used to.. well... play audio on an iPhone. You know, when you're programming for it. The question is most certainly programming related.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The SDK has no provision for reading files from the iPod library (as you'd need to do to use `AVAudioPlayer` with it), probably for anti-piracy reasons. To play iPod library items, use the `MPMusicPlayerController` class.

**Edit: This is no longer accurate.** See the below answers which describe the use of the AVPlayer class.

Comment: This is not true, see the other answers that document how to access the iPod library for use with AVAudioPlayer.

Comment: This may have been true in Dec '09 but it is possible now as Steve Tranby explains in his answer.

Answer (score 20):

As David mentions there is more work to do than this, for example you have to manage playing the next track in a collection of media items, but here is one way to do it with a set of MPMediaItems that a user selected from the iPod Picker. The AssetURL is what you use, it gives you a path to the MP3 file (e.g. ipod-library://item/item.mp3?id=-6889145242935454020)

```
NSURL *anUrl = [[mediaItems objectAtIndex: 0] valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL];
self.audioPlayerMusic = [[[AVPlayer alloc] initWithURL:anUrl] retain];                      
[self.audioPlayerMusic play];
```

Comment: Soory, can not play sound, with AVPlayer. Help is needed.

Comment: This will **not work** for **DRM-protected** songs (like the ones from _Apple Music_ subscription) or for the ones which are not available **offline** but in cloud. If you are interested in checking whether music is DRM-protected or in playing DRM-protected music the right way, read my detailed answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47694472/4331787

Comment: Thanks, for the reply. Here you have explained that how to detect drm track. Please tell me how to play it. I am using AVPlayer but it is not playing. I could play using MPMusicPlayer, but my requirement is I needed to play using AVFoundation.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can play songs from the iPod library using the SDK without resorting to the `MPMusicPlayerController` class.

The more basic `AVPlayer` class can handle audio files from the iPod library by using the `NSUrl` value from the song's `MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL` property. You have to do a lot more work to get everything setup properly, but it can be done.

Comment: I do not know how, but using AVAplat=yer it is not workng.

Answer (score 1):

Is there any possibility to get information about dB-metering in `MPMusicPlayerController`? Perhaps initiating an `AVAudioSession` for Recording in parallel would do the job?? I need dB-values to build some kind of volume-spectrograph.

Comment: 2 year old question, but I will add the answer for anyone else who lands here. To get the dB level from the audio, use Core-Audio's AudioStreamBasicDescription (https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/musicaudio/reference/CoreAudioDataTypesRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004488-CH3-SW2 ) with the audio data as a stream. I am using the URL from the ipod library for the asset and am using the data at the URL with core-audio.

Comment: Can you expand on this answer a little more?

Comment: @Helium3: Is your solution working with IOS10 and DRM protected files, too?

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void)mediaPicker:(MPMediaPickerController *)mediaPicker didPickMediaItems:(MPMediaItemCollection *)mediaItemCollection {
    NSURL *url = [[mediaItemCollection.items objectAtIndex:0] valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL];

    NSError *error;
    self.player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] url error:&error];

    if (!error) {
        [self.player prepareToPlay];
        [self.player play];
    }

    [mediaPicker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```