# Apple Music Offline Files Have no URL?

Tags: ios, objective-c, mpmediaitem

It seems that the property `MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL` on a `MPMediaItem` returns null when the file is one that was from Apple Music and has been made "available offline".

On the other hand, items from my original library which I uploaded to iTunes match/apple music and then make available offline don't seem to have this problem.

Is this a bug? Have I done something wrong? Anyone having similar issues?

Comment: Have you found anything new concerning this issue?

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Ever figure this one out?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that Apple Music files are DRM-protected and subscription based, so probably Apple prohibits the use of references to these assets due to rights management.

Reference: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/7389

Answer (score 0):

Things have changed a little and this isn't true anymore. `MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL` is **not nil** on **iOS 11** for songs saved offline via *Apple Music* but `AVPlayer` is unable to play them since they are still **DRM** protected. The same song returns `MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL` **nil** on **iOS 9**.

If you are interested in checking for DRM protected songs or in playing such songs, you can read my detailed answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47694472/4331787