# What is hasProtectedContent for AVAsset

Tags: ios, avasset

I notice this property `hasProtectedContent` in the `AVAsset` which is very vaguely defined.

> Assets containing protected content may not be playable without successful authorization, even if the value of the `playable` property is YES. [[doc]](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avasset/1389223-hasprotectedcontent?language=objc)

Can someone elaborate what is protected content property means and when it will be `true`? Is it always required (or good practice) to check for this value before attempting to play the video?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure what it means for third party sources, but this property is used to detect whether an asset is **DRM protected** or not. In my case, I use it to check if a chosen song from user's music library is DRM protected or not as the songs from *Apple Music* (subscription) are DRM protected. `hasProtectedContent` is `true` for such songs and `false` for the ones which are DRM-free. Such DRM-protected songs **cannot** be played by `AVPlayer` and only by `MPMusicPlayer`.

If you are interested in detecting whether an asset is DRM protected or in playing such assets the right way, you can read my detailed answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47694472/4331787